# How to change ImageView source from different XML?

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview, imagesource

I want to change images in my popupwindow. I am trying to change ImageView image source which is in `test.xml` while my contentView is `activity_main`. When I try to just call `imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help);` it gives me `nullpointerexception` I realized i have to use inflate method, but when I use it it doesn't do what I want.I know there is a lot of questions regarding this, but none of them really helped me. 
This is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.popupwindow.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:id="@+id/test1"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linear1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my main.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PopupWindow popupWindow;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);

        final View view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.test, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view1.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help); //Image source is not changed in my popupWindow, 
                                                                     // but it is changed when I call relativeLayout.addView(view1);

        test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //relativeLayout.addView(view1); // <-- this does the trick, but its not what i want
                View container = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.test, null);

                popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container, android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(relativeLayout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `setImageDrawable(Drawable d)` and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inflating two separate views. Obviously what you do in one will have no impact on the other. You should set the popup view to your originally inflated view:

```
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(view1,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        true);
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I didn't really understood inflate method, I thought that my first inflate changed the test layout

Comment: Is there any way i can change test layout in my Java code so that when I create View container = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.test, null);, R.layout.test is that new changed test layout?

Comment: No, all resources are static and there is no way to modify them after compiling.